# details:Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: python, django

I am able to authenticate my users to get the token but when i try to view all my users, i get the error `{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}`. I have had a look at other related issues and solutions but i am still not getting it working. **What am i not doing right to solve this issue to view all my users without getting this error**

**settings**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = { 
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

**views.py**

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

**httpd.conf**

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs"

    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

**postman image**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

update your settings.py file to support some additional rest_framework classes -

```
 REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'

    )
}
```

Let me know, if it helps!

Comment: It is still giving the same error. I am able to get the token alright but when i try to view the users by doing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/`, i still get the same error raised

Comment: did you hit this api programmatically or through a browser ? also confirm that you are getting auth token attached to this api call from browser

Comment: I am actually using postman for this. What i do is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/?token=d4nf4400fssfjs3` in the postman and it fails

Comment: token should be used in the request headers I suppose rather than in url query params! . please confirm that first .. for all other apis are you using it in the same way?

Comment: I have updated the question with how i add the token to the headers. Please confirm